# I have a Jinja template that only prints the first match of a regex match but I would like it to print all matches

Tags: regex, loops, ansible, jinja2

I run a playbook that executes a Cisco command show interfaces and I store that into a variable.
I then jump into a template for further processing to only find Ethernet interfaces and errors.

I find the first match of both interface and error which is fine but I do not find the second match of interface and error in the control environment.  The lab device has two interfaces Ethernet0/0 and Ethernet0/1.

Can someone make a suggestion so that I can match on both interfaces and respective errors?

Here is the task:

> Blockquote

```
tasks:
- name: gather interface stats and store in register
  ios_command:
    commands: 
      - show interface | section include is up
  register: interface_errors

- name: store interface_errors_file
  copy:
    content: {{interface_errors}}
    dest: ./{{inventory_hostname}}_interface_full.txt
  
- name: deploy template
  copy:
    content: "{{lookup('template', 'errors.j2') }}"
    dest: ./{{inventory_hostname}}_errors.txt
```

Template:

> Blockquote

```
  {% for int in interface_errors.stdout %}
  {% set int_name = int | regex_search('Ethernet\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3} is up') %}
  {% if 'Ethernet' in int_name | string %}
   - Interface: {{int_name}}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

{% for int_err in interface_errors.stdout %}
{% set int_errors = int_err | regex_search('\d{1,10000}.input.errors|output.errors') %}
{% if 'errors' in int_errors %}
- Interface Errors: {{int_errors}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague to have a concrete answer, but based on your subject: are you aware of [`| regex_findall`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) which returns a `list[str]` of its matches?

Comment: Let me try that and see and thank you!

Comment: that did it the regex_findall and thank you!